# getting the conversion for which the ad is optimised using fb ad insights api

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am facing a very trivial problem with facebook ad_insights API.
I have many campaigns running for me on facebook. They are optimised for different events, like 'purchase','initiate checkout','add to cart'.

When I request the end point, I get a response similar to this,

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "actions": [
        {
          "action_type": "link_click",
          "value": 19
        },
        {
          "action_type": "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "action_type": "offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_view_content",
          "value": 19
        },
        {
          "action_type": "post_like",
          "value": 88
        },
        {
          "action_type": "page_engagement",
          "value": 107
        },
        {
          "action_type": "post_engagement",
          "value": 107
        },
        {
          "action_type": "offsite_conversion",
          "value": 20
        }
      ],
      "spend": 5.16,
      "account_id": "10201496xxxxxxxxxx",
      "campaign_name": "Link Clicks to Website (CPC)",
      "ad_name": "[2015/11/27] New Arrivals",
      "adset_name": "Custom Audience - Visitors or Lookalike - Visitors",
      "impressions": "2634",
      "date_start": "2015-11-01",
      "date_stop": "2015-12-01"
    }, ...
```

as we can see there is `offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_view_content` and there is `offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase`. Some of my campaigns are optimised for purchases and some are for view content. How can I find out which is the event that my campaign is optimised for dynamically from the API response itself?

Comment: I have figured out a hack for this. posting it so it might help. The first offsite_conversion.* key in the response it the actual result event that the campaign is optimised for, Though this is a hack, I am pretty sure that there is some other better way to get the campaign/ adset settings. Will keep this thread posted if i get any further with this.

Answer (score 0):

Hej,

I think you are rather talking about the optimization of an ad set rather a campaign as on the campaign level, you can't set an optimization strategy or bids.

To your problem:
Do you mean the `promoted_object`? 
This gives you the event goal in the custom_event_type (eg CONTENT_VIEW, ADD_TO_CART, PURCHASE...) for the ad set.

When calling the `promoted_object` it will return this:

`"promoted_object": {
 "pixel_id": "<PIXEL-ID>",
 "custom_event_type": "ADD_TO_CART"`